# Jquery, Javascript click menu doesnt work on IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, safari

i´ve created this little menu [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w0b7aqpL/3/) and it works fine on firefox and Chrome. But the function (".class").cick( function() does nothing at IE and Safari.
Maybe someone can help? I´ve tried .live .on("click",".class") etc.. nothing works.
you need to scratch the menu like [this](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4500/szw56p6o_png.htm)

CODE (Javascript)

```
  /*Desktopvariante*/
if ((($(window).width() > 970) && test == 90) || (($(window).width() > 970))) {

    $(function () {

        $(".ClickLevel1").click(function () {    


            $(this).addClass("activeFarbe");                

            $(".navLevel1").addClass("activePfeil", 400);

            $("#listLevel1").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 350);
            return false;
        });

    });



    $(function () {
        $(".ClickLevel2").click(function () {


            $(this).addClass("activeFarbe");     

            $(".navLevel2").addClass("activePfeil",400);


            $("#listLevel2").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 350);
            return false;
        });


    });

    $(function () {
        $(".ClickLevel3").click(function () {

            $(this).addClass("activeFarbe");   

            $(".navLevel3").addClass("activePfeil",400);


            $("#listLevel3").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 350);
            return false;
        });
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Just as a tiny question - why are you using javascript for this? This is a few lines of CSS.

Comment: i want to do an action by clicking and not by hovering

Comment: Yes, and I repeat my question, why are you using JS for this, when CSS can do it for you?

Comment: how can i click with css?
It´s a very long js code, so the easiest way is to solve the problem with IE and Safari...

Comment: can someone please help

Comment: Create a minimal, working demonstration of the code that isn't working, in jsfiddle.net or just via the code snippets here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved
(screen.orientation.angle)
cant be read by safari and IE